# Create list with contains method groups and execute this list

Tags: c#, list, methods

For better explanation here is a GUI  screenshoot :

( can't add small image only link)
[Screen GIU <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRTMT.png)

And here is a all of my code with comments :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media; // to play sounds


namespace Music_PLayer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //List View
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

            // Columns CONSTRUCT
            listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 70);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Music name", 150);

            //combobox  items
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 4");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 5");
        }

        // ADD TO List VIEW
        private void add(int ID, string name_music)
        {
            string[] row = { Convert.ToString(ID), name_music };

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        //button to delete selected items in list view
        private void button_delete_selected_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listView1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
            }
            catch { }

        }
**//EDITED :**
        // buttton to add music to list view
        int i = 0;
        private void button_add_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex==0)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 1", playmusic1);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 2", playmusic2);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 3", playmusic3);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 4", playmusic4);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 5", playmusic5);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }

        }

        // button to start music
        private void button_start_music(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        // Voids with music :
        public void playmusic1()
        {

            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound1);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic2()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound2);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic3()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound3);
            audio.Play();

        }
            public void playmusic4()
            {
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound4);
                audio.Play();
            }
            public void playmusic5()
            {
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound5);
                audio.Play();
            }
                public delegate void PlayMusic();
// EDITED 
        Dictionary<string, PlayMusic> dictOfDelegate = new Dictionary<string, PlayMusic>();

        void CreateList()
        {
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 1", playmusic1);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 2", playmusic2);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 3", playmusic3);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 4", playmusic4);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 5", playmusic5);
        }

    void InvokeMethod(string item)
    {
        PlayMusic method = dictOfDelegate.First(x => x.Key == item).Value;

        method.Invoke();
    }
    }
}
```

I want to to select a song from the combobox to add it to the playlist that will play from top to bottom after clicking on the "Start Music" button..

I would like to add a selected song from the combobox to the listview when you click the "Add Music to list" button. Of course, with the "Delete selected music" button I have the ability to delete a song from the list.

So I have to do so for example when I select from the combobox (Music1) click on the button (Add Music to list), it will display ID 1 Music name Music 1 and when click on the Start Music button it will execute void playmusic1 ();

I know I just only add text from combobox to listview but i don't know how can I get method there...

I really don't know how to code Start Music button ( i thinking about queue) to play music one by one with my listView1.

All I need is Collection or something or Queue.

The main question is how to create a list whith contains a  method gorups and later execute all this list ( as you see i want to have possible to remove  selected element on this list )

If I dont explain exacly just ask..

**EDIT...**

I think  the best solution is this code :

```
 public  List<Action> musiclist = new   List<Action>();

  // buttton to add music to list view
        int i = 0;
        private void button_add_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex==0)
            {

                musiclist.Add(playmusic1);
                add(i, comboBox1.Text);
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                musiclist.Add(playmusic2);
                add(i, comboBox1.Text);

            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                musiclist.Add(playmusic3);
                add(i, comboBox1.Text);
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                musiclist.Add(playmusic4);
                add(i, comboBox1.Text);
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                musiclist.Add(playmusic5);
                add(i, comboBox1.Text);
            }
        }
   private void button_to_Start_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Action func in musiclist)
        {
            func();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to queue method-calls, a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) of sound ids is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me the best approach to do it, anyway you could use delegates in a Dictionary.

```
public delegate void PlayMusic();

Dictionary<string, PlayMusic> dictOfDelegate = new Dictionary<string, PlayMusic>();

void CreateList()
{        
    dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 1", playmusic1);
    dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 2", playmusic2);
    ...
}

void InvokeMethod(string item)
{
    PlayMusic method = dictOfDelegate.First(x => x.Key == item).Value;

    method.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thank you man for help,  i added your code to main code just look first post. Anyway could you check i did it correct?I edited my button_add_music please look on it too.  And i have trouble when i add for example:  Music 1 and again Music 1 it's display a bug and can't add 2 the same music to my list. 2nd problem is how should i write correctly my  button_start_music . Could you help a little? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Don't use Linq `First` method to get the delegate from the dictionary. Use `PlayMusic method = dictOfDelegate[item];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class Song and a list that you could add or remove things at any time from.

```
    int queueSize = 0;
    int queueCurrent = 0;
    List<Song> toPlay = new List<Song>();
    class Manager
    {
        public void addSong(Song add)
        {
            toPlay.add(add);
            queueSize++;
        }
        public void removeSong(int remove)
        {
            toPlay.RemoveAt(remove)
            queueSize--;
        }
        public void playSong(int index)
        {
            Song play = toPlay[index]
            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer songPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            songPlayer.URL = play.FilePath;
            wplayer.Controls.Play();
        }
    }
    class Song
    {
        string FilePath;
        string Name;
        int Index;
        public Song(string name, int index)
        {
            Name = name;
            Index = index;
        }
    }
```

Of course this would take a bit more code but this should solve your problem. If you have any questions or see any edits tell me in the comments.

**EDIT**: The OP was looking for a hard coded way for each song so here it is. Also I do not recommend doing this for anyone else looking for the same answer.

```
    class Songs
    {
       public void songOne()
       {
           string name = "songOne";
           string path = "C:/songs/songone/
           playSong(path);
       }
       public void songOne()
       {
           string name = "songTwo";
           string path = "C:/songs/songtwo/
           playSong(path);
       }
       // And all the other songs
       public void playSong(string path)
       {
           WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer songPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            songPlayer.URL = path;
            wplayer.Controls.Play();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i can do that as you said but i want do this by method so each song has own method as in my example . I want do that just this way not another. You show me play song in 1 method.  I just want do this by this way. Have you any another solution to do it how i want?

Comment: Why would you want to give every song it's own method? This is a standard object oriented way of doing things. Hard coding everything assures it will work, but you lose all flexibility. If you were looking for a hard coded way I can show you in the answer.

Comment: i have another program with contains 20 methond . Every method has diffrent everything ect. And point of this program is to make waypoints like  i said in this program.I just need that you know how can i do that?

Comment: I put in a way of hardcoding the songs in.

Comment: look main topic Edited. I just create a new list of methods. And can set every song by song. But do you know how can i delete exacly  a song? by click button to delete from list i want to delete this song  . You know what  i mean.

Comment: The reason I made the original is that is the basic logic behind how to make everything as dynamic as possible. When you program you never want to limit yourself to the boundaries of hard coding. Of course I didn't program it for you, you would have to fit that logic to your situation, but the way I made it is the most dynamic and fits the most with standard OOP format. Another thing, methods by normal convention don't include underscores, but instead use camelCase like this `public void playSong` and `public int calcIndex`. They also should be short, so they are quick to call and refrence.